# net.sf.ehcache.ObjectExistsException: The Default Cache has already been configured

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache, database-caching

I am using Spring (4.2.6.RELEASE) with Hibernate(5.1.0.Final). Hibernate properties defined as a bean in spring.xml.
And i added ehcache for second-level caching library. 
I am getting error **net.sf.ehcache.ObjectExistsException: The Default Cache has already been configured** in following project.
Is there anybody to help?

***************************** applicationContext-dao.xml  **************************************

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="databaseProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="file:///C:/Config/database.properties"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionDatasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="transactionDatasource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.company.model.db.ApplicationStatEntity</value>
                <value>com.company.DeviceCapEntity</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@<IP>:1522/rac2</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache.xml</prop>
                <!--property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache.xml</property-->

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I implemented following GenericDao Class. This class gets entities as generic.

***************************** GenericDao  **********************

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;



public class GenericDaoImpl<GenericEntity> implements GenericDao<GenericEntity> {

    private Class<GenericEntity> type;
    private ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = null;
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(GenericDaoImpl.class.getName());

    public GenericDaoImpl() {
        context = getApplicationContext();
        sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();
    }

    private ClassPathXmlApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        if (this.context == null) {
            this.context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext-dao.xml");
        }
        return this.context;
    }

    private SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if(this.sessionFactory==null) {
            this.sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) getApplicationContext().getBean("hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory");
        }
        return this.sessionFactory;
    }

    public Class<GenericEntity> getMyType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public void setType(Class<GenericEntity> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }


    public void insert(GenericEntity genericEntity) throws DaoException {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            log.info("[GeneicDaoImpl.insert]  hibernate session opened");
            session.save(genericEntity);
            log.info("[GeneicDaoImpl.insert]  insertion done");
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (QuerySyntaxException e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
                log.error(
                        "[GeneicDaoImpl.insert]  An error occured ID generation with table mapping. "
                        + "Check schema,table name in entity object or check table in database",
                        e);
                throw new DaoException("[GeneicDaoImpl.insert]  hibernate error occured,rollback done. Stack Trace : /n" + e.getStackTrace());
            }
        } catch (AnnotationException e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
                log.error("[GeneicDaoImpl.insert]  An error occured ID generation with sequence. Check sequence name in entity object and in database",
                          e);
                throw new DaoException("[GeneicDaoImpl.insert]  hibernate error occured,rollback done. Stack Trace : /n" + e.getStackTrace());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
                log.error("[GeneicDaoImpl.insert]  hibernate error occured,rollback done", e);
                throw new DaoException("[GeneicDaoImpl.insert]  hibernate error occured,rollback done. Stack Trace : /n" + e.getStackTrace());
            }

        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And in Junit Test Class, I call insert batch like this.

************************** TestClass.java *****************************

```
    public class TestClass {

        @Test
        public void insertTest() {
            GenericDao<ApplicationStatEntity> insertBatchDao = new GenericDaoImpl();
            ApplicationStatEntity applicationStatEntity = new ApplicationStatEntity();
            applicationStatEntity.setId(102);
            applicationStatEntity.setDeviceid("SamsungShitty");
            try {
                insertBatchDao.insert(applicationStatEntity);
            } catch (DaoException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

***************************** ehcache.xml  **********************

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache>

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir/ehcache" />

    <defaultCache maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000" eternal="false"
                  timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120" diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
                  maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
                  memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" statistics="true">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </defaultCache>


</ehcache>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use cache tag instead of defaultCache.

ehcache.xml can be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache>
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir/ehcache" />

    <defaultCache maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000" eternal="false"
                  timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120" diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
                  maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
                  memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" statistics="true">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
    </defaultCache>



    <cache name="sampleCache" 
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000" 
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120" 
        timeToLiveSeconds="120" 
        diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
        maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000" 
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" 
        statistics="true">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>

</ehcache>
```

From ehcache documentation

```
<!--

Default Cache configuration. These settings will be applied to caches
created programmatically using CacheManager.add(String cacheName).
This element is optional, and using CacheManager.add(String cacheName) when
its not present will throw CacheException

The defaultCache has an implicit name "default" which is a reserved cache name.

-->

<defaultCache maxEntriesLocalHeap="0" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="1200" timeToLiveSeconds="1200">
    <terracotta/>
</defaultCache>
```